# Qunit: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: ember.js, gruntjs, qunit, ember-qunit

These are the tests I've written so far. This first assertion passes. For the second I get the error: `TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

```
/*global describe, it, assert */
App.rootElement = '#emberTestingDiv';

App.setupForTesting();
App.injectTestHelpers();

module('Integration Tests', {
  setup: function() {
    App.reset();
  }
});


// Tests

test('search terms?', function() {
  App.mainSearcher.params.q = 'our keywords';
  equal(App.mainSearcher.params.q, 'our keywords');
});

test('router?', function() {
  visit('/search?q=method&sort=patAssignorEarliestExDate%20desc');
  andThen(function(){
    equal(find('title').text(), 'method');
  });
});
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting that. I'm using grunt-contrib-qunit so I'm curious if I did something wrong with setting qunit up with the Ember app via grunt/npm.

But I don't think that's it because the first test is passing.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Edit:

Here's the full error

```
Died on test #1 at file:///Users/jwhite/Documents/workspace/uspto-aotw/front-end/test/spec/test.js:21:1: undefined is not a function
Source: TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Line 21 is the first line for the second test:

```
test('router?', function() {
```

Comment: what exactly is not a function?

Answer (score 1):

My guess? Something in the first test run "unsets" the global `test` variable/method. My recommendation is instead to use the fully qualified version of the QUnit API:

```
/*global describe, it, assert */
App.rootElement = '#emberTestingDiv';

App.setupForTesting();
App.injectTestHelpers();

QUnit.module('Integration Tests', {   // qualified
  setup: function() {
    App.reset();
  }
});


// Tests

QUnit.test('search terms?', function(assert) {   // qualified (with `assert` arg)
  App.mainSearcher.params.q = 'our keywords';
  assert.equal(App.mainSearcher.params.q, 'our keywords');  // qualified
});

QUnit.test('router?', function(assert) {   // qualified (with `assert` arg)
  visit('/search?q=method&sort=patAssignorEarliestExDate%20desc');
  andThen(function(){
    assert.equal(find('title').text(), 'method');   // qualified
  });
});
```

If that works, then my assumption is correct, but I have no idea how that could happen in your first test run since it doesn't really do anything. I suppose it could be something in `App.reset()`, but then why is `test()` defined the first time?

In any case... try the qualified method calls first, could be a quick fix.

Comment: The same thing happens with the code you provided. The first test passes and the second will fail. If I comment out the first test, the second test still fails.

Comment: So, too narrow down the issue, can you add a test in between the existing two and just make it: `assert.ok(true);` ?

Comment: I would also try removing the `setup` method in the QUnit module and see if you can just get any sequence of tests to run (even if they fail).

Comment: If I have assert.ok(true); then the test fails saying assert not defined. If I take assert out and have ok(true); then the test will pass.

If I take out setup:function() { App.reset()" } then I get the same results as if I did have it.

Comment: The `assert` variable must be passed into the `test` callback function (see the examples above).

Comment: OK. That works then with setup function commented out and left in.

Comment: Cool... so then, are you still getting the error when you use your actual tests and the fully-qualified QUnit methods?

Comment: Yes. For the router? test I still get Undefined is not a function for the line that starts the 'test'.

Comment: Are you using `test()` or `QUnit.test()` ? I'm confused about what is working and what is not...

Comment: Also, the [Ember site](http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/integration/) suggests putting the `App.reset();` call in a `teardown` callback (versus `setup`), can you try that?